# Need help with a difficult MS SQL query - Selecting back metro area counts

Tags: sql-server

I am working with a fairly large data set (1.2 million records). I am trying to identify the top 25 US Cities in my data set (most number of records per city).

So I wrote this query to select back the list.

```
Select PHY_CITY, PHY_STATE, count(*) as counter 
from tblMyData
group by PHY_CITY, PHY_STATE
Order by counter desc, PHY_CITY, PHY_STATE
```

After analyzing this data I have come to realize that although this returns solid numbers, it is not what I am looking for. I have limited my results to only records within the immediate physical city limits of a city. For example, the actual city limits of Atlanta GA has a very small footprint, only 540K+ residents. However, what is considered the metropolitan area of Atlanta, consists of 28 counties and has a population exceeding 5.4 million residents!

I do have Zip Codes in my data set but I do not have county or metro region as a field. Is there any data source out there that takes all the zip codes or city names in the Us and defines them by metropolitan region?

What I really want is to know the top 25 metropolitan areas in my data, not just proper city limits.

Answer (score 0):

There are some excel files with Metro areas by zip on the bottom of this census page. Perhaps you could import and use that with your data:

http://www.census.gov/population/www/metroareas/metroarea.html